# How to find work done by heated gas and what causes the piston to move based on the problem

Tags: thermodynamics

[image][image]
So I had this problem, and I have 2 questions :
1. From the problem written in the picture, what causes the piston to move upwards? If it because of the pressure, then based on formula PV=nRT, if the pressure increases then the Volume must have decreased right? But in the problem the volume increases. Also if its heated the temperature must have increased too. So, how do I solve this problem?
2. How to find work done based on the problem

Comment: why would you think the pressure in the piston increases?

Comment: Otherwise the piston wouldn't have moved right? The force that move the piston is equal to F=p.S. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: doesn't the piston (this thing of mass $M$) move up or down?  The walls of the cylinder do not move.  Or is it late and I can't read straight?

Comment: Up, from h to 3/2 h

Comment: so this will increase the volume of the gas inside the piston, decrease the pressure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a force balance on the piston, you get $Mg=(2p_0-p_0)S$.  When the gas is heated, the piston mass M doesn't change, the outside pressure $p_0$ doesn't change, and the piston area S doesn't change.  So, from the force balance, the gas pressure remains at $2p_0$.  The increase in temperature is compensated by the increase in volume.  So the force exerted by the gas on the piston during the heating is constant at $2p_0S$.  The work the gas does is the force the gas exerts on the piston times the displacement, h/2.

Comment: so, the force exerted by the gas before its heated and after its heated still the same because the pressure doesnt change. Instead the piston moves because of the increase of the volume

Comment: The gas exerts an **insignificantly** higher pressure on the piston during the expansion.